# Entity list relationships in Android Room

Tags: android, database, orm, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to load entity sublist, but i would like to avoid to do 2 queries.

I'm thinking about do query inside TypeConverter, but i really don't know if it's good idea.

My entities:

```
@Entity
class Region(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Int = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        var locales: List<Locale> = listOf())

@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(
        entity = Region::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("regionId"),
        onDelete = CASCADE,
        onUpdate = CASCADE
)))
class Locale(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Int = 0,
        var regionId: Int = 0,
        var name: String = "")
```

DAOs :

```
@Dao
interface RoomRegionDao{
    @Insert
    fun insert(region: Region)

    @Delete
    fun delete(region: Region)

    @Query("select * from region")
    fun selectAll(): Flowable<List<Region>>
}

@Dao
interface RoomLocaleDao{
    @Insert
    fun insert(locale: Locale)

    @Query("select * from locale where regionId = :arg0")
    fun selectAll(regionId: Int): List<Locale>
}
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Region::class, Locale::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(RoomAppDatabase.Converters::class)
abstract class RoomAppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun regionDao(): RoomRegionDao
    abstract fun localeDao(): RoomLocaleDao

    inner class Converters {
        @TypeConverter
        fun toLocales(regionId: Int): List<Locale> {
            return localeDao().selectAll(regionId)
        }

        @TypeConverter
        fun fromLocales(locales: List<Locale>?): Int {
            locales ?: return 0
            if (locales.isEmpty()) return 0

            return locales.first().regionId
        }
    }
}
```

It's not working because can't use inner class as converter class.

- Is it a good way?
- How can I load "locales list" automatically in region entity when I do `RoomRegionDao.selectAll`?

Comment: Just when I was about to give up on kotlin and Room your question saved me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `TypeConverter` only works for static methods.
I say this based on the example from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#type-converters) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter.html)

From the relationships section [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data.html#object-relationships):

> "Because SQLite is a relational database, you can specify relationships between objects. Even though most ORM libraries allow entity objects to reference each other, Room explicitly forbids this."

So I guess it's best if you add `@Ignore` on your `locales` property and make a method on `RoomLocaleDao` thats insert `List<Locale>` and call it after insert Region.

The method that inserts a Region can return the [inserted id](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#daos-convenience).

> If the @Insert method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a long, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return long[] or List instead.
>   (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#daos-convenience)

Comment: Yes thx for the answer. The only way is to make high level interface, so i make RegionDao wich use RoomRegionDao and RoomLocaleDao to return regions with locales loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all your `Regions` wit a list of `Locales` inside each `Region` just with one `Query`.

All you need to do is create a new `Relation` like this:

```
data class RegionWithLocale(
    @Embedded
    val region: Region,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entity = Locale::class,
        entityColumn = "regionId"
    )
    val locales: List<Locale>
)
```

And latter get that relation in your `Dao` like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM region WHERE id IS :regionId")
fun getRegions(regionId: Int): LiveData<RegionWithLocale>

@Query("SELECT * FROM region")
fun getAllRegions(): LiveData<List<RegionWithLocale>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

**ListConvert.kt**

```
class ListConverter
{
    companion object
    {
        var gson = Gson()

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun fromTimestamp(data: String?): List<Weather>?
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                return Collections.emptyList()
            }

            val listType = object : TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.type
            return gson.fromJson(data, listType)
        }

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun someObjectListToString(someObjects: List<Weather>?): String?
        {
            return gson.toJson(someObjects)
        }
    }
}
```

**The property inside of my Entity**

```
@SerializedName("weather")
@TypeConverters(ListConverter::class)
val weather: List<Weather>,
```

Comment: This is not recommended because you can't query `Weather` directly from SQL if needed